# dialog/whiptail radiolist consistence

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, dialog

So basically I am trying to rewrite a bash script which uses dialog --radiolist for choosing locale,keyboard,time. At the moment the tag is a number that corresponds to a local (I created a hashtable for it). But because I have, and want to keep it that way for now, around 100 locales it gets messy at the end.

What I wanna achieve is to make it more compact without having to add  or add an artificial, non visible item that might easily translate to its tag. (as a tag I would put the locale name)

What I have tried:
1. Noobish thing but I though that there might be some way to include empty like NULL in ASCII or 0, blank space etc, but dialog would always make it visible.
2. Exclude the item at all and finish on on/off but instead on/off takes place of item (not surprisingly if options are as follow --radiolist text height width list-height [ tag item status ])
3. Instead of letting the dialog on exit write to the output the name of the chosen locale I created an output statement myself.

I had red a lot about dialog and whiptail(http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog, http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_dialog.php) but always end up with having to add tag and an item. Would appreciate any suggestions and maybe some info if there is easily plug-gable dialog/whiptail compatible libs.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you overlooked the `--no-tags` option (see [manpage](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html)):

> **`--no-tags`**
>
> Some  widgets  (*checklist*, *inputmenu*, *radiolist*, menu) display a
>   list with two columns (a "tag" and "description").  The  tag  is
>   useful  for scripting, but may not help the user.  The `--no-tags`
>   option (from Xdialog) may be used to suppress the column of tags
>   from  the  display.  Unlike the `--no-items` option, this does not
>   affect the data which is read from the script.

The question mentions whiptail and consistency, which could refer to consistency across dialog and whiptail.  There is none, since

- whiptail provides fewer options than dialog (inevitably, there will be differences, since there is no one-one mapping possible)
- consistency as such between the two is done in dialog occasionally to help with compatibility (the reverse is not true).

Comment: Just tried that. Looks good and does what I want but, just for the cosmetic of the look, is there, i tried to search for that, to mix dialog with whiptail as --notags/items options seems not to be ported

Comment: It does not appear that whiptail has `--no-tags` or `--notags`.  According to dialog's [changelog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/CHANGES.html#t20121230), that came from `Xdialog`.  whiptail's manpage does list `--noitem`.

Comment: It has --notags option (--no-tags was ported to dialog but seems to not working there). I am looking into zenity. Maybe you know aby program that might actually produce something not from 20th Century. ?

Comment: You can see when features were added to dialog by reading its [changelog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/CHANGES.html).